# Función que devuelve la fecha para el primer día del mes

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL dispone de la funcción [LAST_DAY(date)](http://mysql.conclase.net/curso/?sqlfun=LAST_DAY) que devuelve la fecha para el último día del mes:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(fecha) AS ultimo_dia
FROM table
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener la fecha para el primer día del mes?

Comment: Last day devuelve el ultimo dia del mes porque , depende el mes se pueden presentar variaciones entre 28,29,30 o 31 pero el primer dia del mes es siempre el mismo

Comment: @Santi92 Se refiere a la fecha para el primer día del mes... no a calcular el primer día del mes. No se, imagínate que tienes una serie de resultados y quieres agruparlos por fecha y esa fecha ha de ser el primer día de cada mes

Comment: @eferion ahora entendi,gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se me ocurren estas dos alternativas:

```
SELECT fecha - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(fecha) - 1 DAY;

SELECT SUBDATE(fecha, DAYOFMONTH(fecha) - 1);
```

Ambas involucran sólo 2 llamados a funciones. Seguro diferirán en eficiencia en base a si el `INTERVAL` se calcula más rápidamente que el `SUBDATE`.

Comment: todas las respuestas son buenas, pero esta es la que yo mas prefiero, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 6):

Al parecer no hay una función que devuelva el primer día del mes, deberías crearla, y es más o menos así:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION FIRST_DAY(day DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN ADDDATE(LAST_DAY(SUBDATE(day, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1);
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

y lo utilizarías de esta manera

```
SELECT FIRST_DAY('2010-06-15');
```

[fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158513/2616405)

Comment: Pero el primer dia del mes es siempre el mismo, cual es el sentido de la función ?

Comment: @Santi92 Supongo que el objetivo es que esta función sea utilizable de la misma forma que `LAST_DAY()`. Sin embargo, el problema que veo es que, si se desea usar con otra base de datos activa, habría que llamar a la función como `db1.FIRST_DAY()`... Y para usarla en otro servidor habría que asegurarse de que la función esté creada. Esta es una buena solucón, pero no es particularmente "portable"

Answer (score 5):

**Primer dia del mes**

```
select now() - interval (day(now())-1) day
```

**Primer dia del mes siguiente :** es simplemente el último día + 1

```
select adddate(last_day(curdate()), 1)
```

**Fuente:** extraido de StacOverFlow disponible en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009896/get-the-first-and-last-date-of-next-month-in-mysql

Comment: Es correcto por eso deje la fuente, pero como pregunto y nunca volvio a responder que precisaba, ahi deje las dos soluciones de la version en ingles

Answer (score 4):

Una opción rápida: crea una nueva fecha concatenando el año y mes de la fecha, y especifica un 1 para el día. El código sería así:

```
SELECT DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(fecha), MONTH(fecha), '1')) AS primer_dia
FROM   mitabla
```

---

Podrías guardar ese código en una función:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FIRST_DAY(fecha DATE) 
RETURNS DATE
RETURN DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', YEAR(fecha), MONTH(fecha), '1'))
```

Y llamar a la función directamente desde el `SELECT`:

```
SELECT fecha, FIRST_DAY(fecha) 
FROM   mitabla
```

Answer (score 3):

Probando en mi BD, creo que esto podría funcionar aplicada a una tabla:

```
SELECT 
    LAST_DAY(fecha_creacion - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
FROM 
    tabla;
```

**Actualización:**

Al parecer solo funciona bien si le pasas un registro específico:

```
SELECT 
    LAST_DAY(fecha_creacion - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
FROM 
    tabla 
WHERE 
    campo_id=id;
```

Si quisieras saber, por ejemplo, de una tabla el primer día del mes con respecto a todos los registros, podrías agregar `MAX` al query:

```
SELECT 
    LAST_DAY(MAX(fecha_creacion) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY   
FROM 
    tabla;
```

Answer (score 3):

simplemente impleméntalo de esta manera:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-01') as primer_dia
 FROM table
```

sin tener necesidad de funciones adicionales.

Answer (score 1):

Encontre una solución gracias a las guias arriba mencionadas y logre obtener el primer día del mes de la siguiente forma:

```
(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY))
```

Con esto lo que hace es que obtiene la fecha omitiendo la hora, ahora bien si lo que quieres es la fecha y hora pues reemplaza CURRENT_DATE por NOW().

CURRENT_DATE devuelve 2017-09-01, mientras NOW() devuelve:2017-09-01 02:10:39

Un ejemplo de query para que sirva de guia:

```
SELECT saldoInicial FROM ventas WHERE fecha = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY))
```

En si es más ordenado ya que te devuelve el tipo DATE.

Answer (score 1):

Hay una forma muy portable que me funciona....

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-01');
```

Respuesta: 2019-08-01